# Default cell value on insert row from Forms

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a live quiz with results from a Google form. It inserts rows into my custom sheet, but one of the values which is a `sum()` of specific cells is ignored on insertion, is there a way to set the default value of a specific cell when a new row is inserted to the specific sum formula I require?
I have seen various examples but all are more complex than I need an I am unable to unpick them.

Is it also possible to specify a checkbox in a cell as well?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: messaged you with URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"TOTAL"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A9:A="",,MMULT(FILTER(D9:CE, 
 MOD(COLUMN(D9:CE)-1, 2)=0)*1, ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D:CE)/2))^0)))}
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15vbm16zqkClH-ex5Tp6UVibXxk9KXR6E4UmdmkB7h08/copy)